# How to check available webcams from the command line?

Tags: command-line, webcam

Is there a terminal command that lists all the webcams connected to my computer including the native one? Maybe using the `ffmpeg` package?

Comment: <<<<< lsusb >>>>

Answer (score 204, accepted):

**`v4l2-ctl --list-devices`**

```
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

Sample output with a single camera:

```
Integrated Camera (usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6):
        /dev/video0
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

**`video1` metadata device**

On Ubuntu 19.10 Lenovo Thinkpad P51 however, it lists two such devices, `video0` and `video1`, but I only have one camera, and can only see images from `video0` with `ffplay`. This has been asked at:

- [Four /dev/video entries but just one camera](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123601/four-dev-video-entries-but-just-one-camera)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512759/multiple-dev-video-for-one-physical-device

What happens is that `/dev/video1` contains some kind of video metadata only and not the images as can been seen from:

```
sudo v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --all
sudo v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video1 --all
```

which shows respectively:

```
        Device Caps      : 0x04200001
                Video Capture 

        Device Caps      : 0x04a00000
                Metadata Capture
```

**How to see the camera image live**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3304/how-do-i-watch-my-webcams-feed-in-linux
- [What webcam apps are available and how to check if your webcam is working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48245/webcam-apps-and-ways-of-checking-if-webcam-is-working)

My favorite:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
ffplay /dev/video0
```

[image]

Another good one that shows only camera and nothing else:

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
guvcview
```

[image]

**Take a single picture from the command line**

[Take a picture from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106770/take-a-picture-from-terminal)

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -frames 1 out.jpg
```

**Record a video from the command line**

- [Webcam video recorder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661758/webcam-video-recorder)
- [capturing video from webcam and saving to a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161940/capturing-video-from-webcam-and-saving-to-a-file)
- [Anything better than Cheese for video capture?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186003/anything-better-than-cheese-for-video-capture)

Parameters chosen based on "How to get camera parameters like resolution" below:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -c copy out.mkv
```

Then:

```
ffprobe out.mkv
```

contains as expected:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
```

If you choose wrong parameters, the resolution might be slow. The camera already outputs a specific encoded format, and the simplest way to record is to just copy that format as above:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292785/recording-from-webcam-using-ffmpeg-at-high-framerate
- https://superuser.com/questions/1021899/what-ffmpeg-settings-to-get-the-best-possible-video-resolution-framerate-that-my

TODO If I replace `-c copy out.mkv` with `out.ogv` to try and record directly to an open format (unlike MJPEG), I got a low resolution video.

**Interactive image/video capture with preview**

[Picture/Video capture programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9775/picture-video-capture-programs)

Until I learn how to run `ffplay` preview on one shell and capture at the same time from another shell with `ffmpeg` (they fight over the video device), I'll have to lower myself to this amazing GUI program:

```
sudo apt install cheese
```

[image]

**Read camera data from C/C++**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290834/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-linux-ubuntu-c

A concrete C++ example that processes images from the camera on the GPU with OpenGL and shows it live: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693946/image-processing-with-glsl-shaders/40641014#40641014

[image]

**How to get camera parameters like resolution**

- [How can I find out the supported webcam resolutions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214977/how-can-i-find-out-the-supported-webcam-resolutions)
- https://superuser.com/questions/639738/how-can-i-list-the-available-video-modes-for-a-usb-webcam-in-linux

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
```

produces some good information:

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x180
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 352x288
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 424x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x360
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 848x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 960x540
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
    [1]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x180
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 352x288
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 424x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x360
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 848x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 960x540
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
```

**How to get the corresponding ffmpeg encodings**

`v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` gives the Linux kernel name of things, e.g . `YUYV 4:2:2`. But to do stuff with `ffmpeg`, you need to know the ffmpeg nama sometimes. You can do it like this:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
```

sample output:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x555ba7267240] Raw       :     yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : 640x480 320x180 320x240 352x288 424x240 640x360 848x480 960x540 1280x720
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x555ba7267240] Compressed:       mjpeg :          Motion-JPEG : 640x480 320x180 320x240 352x288 424x240 640x360 848x480 960x540 1280x720
```

This for example told us that the ffmpeg name for `YUYV 4:2:2` is `yuyv422`.

**Just having some fun at this point**

```
python -m pip install -U yolov5==7.0.9
yolov5 detect --source 0
```

[image]

Tested on Ubuntu 22.10, Lenovo ThinkPad P51. Ludicrously low GIF resolution uploaded here to fit the 2 MB max Stack Exchange image size, raw at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MD3Wn7e6OE showing that it handles my actual camera resolution.

Comment: On 16.04.1 error: `Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Xaqron also try installing `libv4l-dev` if not already installed. Also give computer model if you can. Cheers.

Comment: Just because I keep coming back to this answer, it's now: `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`. That's lower in the answer but the top in bold text doesn't have the 2.

Comment: $ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory

Comment: This doesn't work if I have a Sony PS3 eye camera connected to my ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @MonaJalal thanks for the report. Please send a bug report to their upstream mailing list: https://www.linuxtv.org/lists.php and link to the thread here. I'm expecting your camera does work with other programs, but clarify that as well on the report.

Comment: Use 'sudo v4l2-ctl --list-devices'

Comment: Beware that it says 4l2, not 412. (Unrelated to other comments.)

Comment: this is the correct actual answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Pablo, thanks for the edit, but I think I prefer the previous format on most points.

Comment: @CiroSantilliПутлерКапут六四事 Can you take a look at my problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417432/why-acer-webcam-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-20-04 please?

Comment: using the ffmpeg command, you can build a cron job entry with webcam.sh:
`DATETIME=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") && ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -frames 1 /home/$USER/Pictures/$DATETIME.jpg 1> /home/$USER/Pictures/webcam.log 2>&1`
be aware to replace $USER with the actual string for a line in "crontab -e": `*/30 * * * * /tmp/webcam.sh`

Comment: excellent answer!

Answer (score 84):

To list all video devices picked up by the kernel

```
ls -ltrh /dev/video*
```

To list all devices attached to USB use `lsusb` ;  to list all devices attached to PCI use `lspci`

Comment: $ ls -ltrh /dev/video*
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory

Comment: @MonaJalal That means it couldn’t find any devices.

Comment: this does not work on my surface pro 3.  I can use cheese and it detects my camera just fine but lspci and the command above both do not show information about the webcam hardware.  This is especially important because I want to use Kamera which asks to select from a long list.

Comment: The "-ltrh" in the "ls" command seems to be a bit of overkill "ls -l /dev/video*" should suffice. The -"t" sorts by time, the "-r" reverses the sort order and the "-h" gives you "human readable" sizes -- none of which appear very helpful here. Not harmful, but unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows you can use the pygrabber library: https://github.com/bunkahle/pygrabber

To check the user friendly names of the connected webcams:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pygrabber.dshow_graph import FilterGraph

graph = FilterGraph()
print(graph.get_input_devices())
```