# Why Acer webcam does not work on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: webcam

The integrated webcam is not working(Lenovo Thinkpad). The light is on but the screen is black(Skype zoom whatever).

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:c123 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 27c6:55a2 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix FingerPrint Device
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a2c:99f4 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Gaming Keyboard 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:2137 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
```

ANd

```
lsmod | grep video
uvcvideo              106496  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       61440  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
videodev              249856  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     57344  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
video                  53248  1 ideapad_laptop
```

I tried similar SO issue solution

```
 ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -frames 1 out2.jpg
ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1364.570108, bitrate: 147456 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1280x720, 147456 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x55def64ba100] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'out2.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc), 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=1.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.10 bitrate=N/A speed=11.6x    
video:17kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

I got black scree image
[image]

How to check this and find the root cause?

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to actually help, but it would be good to say your exact thinkpad model. Me works on P51, integrated camera is `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5ab Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera`.  Would also be good to show the output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`  and check if you got any `/dev/video*`.

Comment: @CiroSantilliПутлерКапут六四事 Thanks. I solved it,the problem is that they use that shit slider (for privacy protection). Now it works fine.